# lvalue required as left operand of assignment - function pointer

Tags: c, linux, kernel, function-pointers, system-calls

I'm working on homework for kernel programming and memory management classes. I need to dynamically obtain the `sys_call_table` address and install a simple hook, which calls the original sys_call (in this case `sys_read`) right after printing some text.

To begin with, I hard-coded the `sys_call_table` address I got using grep and /boot/System.map and followed some code examples I found online:

1. https://gajastechnologies.blogspot.com/2016/12/basics-of-making-rootkit-from-syscall.html
2. https://syprog.blogspot.com/2011/10/hijack-linux-system-calls-part-iii.html

The posts offer different takes on the sys_call_table addresses, namely one uses a single pointer, while the other uses a double. However, in both cases I'm getting the error `lvalue required as left operand of assignment` for the assignment `original_read = table[__NR_read];`

- Where's my mistake? Did something change for newer kernels?
- You'll notice I left two methods for disabling memory read-only
  protection, are both suitable for newer 5.X 32-bit kernels?
- How would one go about obtaining the sys_call_table dynamically
  within the code, what would be used as reference? I haven't been able
  to find information on the exported sys_calls for newer versions. I found `sys_close` being used often, but the compiler doesn't recognize it and suggests the use of `ksys_close` instead.

Code:

```c
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/printk.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/kallsyms.h>
#include <linux/compat.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <uapi/asm/unistd.h>

#include <asm/cacheflush.h>
#include <linux/highmem.h>
#include <asm/pgtable_types.h>

#define DISABLE_W_PROTECTED_MEMORY \
    preempt_disable(); \
    barrier(); \
    write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~ 0x00010000));

#define ENABLE_W_PROTECTED_MEMORY \
    write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x00010000); \
    barrier(); \
    preempt_enable();

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");

asmlinkage long *original_read(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);
asmlinkage long modified_read(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count) {
    pr_info("sys_read\n");
    return original_read(fd, buf, count);
}

void **table = (void *)0xc16e7180;

/*Make page writeable*/

int make_rw(unsigned long address){
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(address, &level);
    if(pte->pte &~_PAGE_RW){
        pte->pte |=_PAGE_RW;
    }
    return 0;
}

/* Make the page write protected */

int make_ro(unsigned long address){
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(address, &level);
    pte->pte = pte->pte &~_PAGE_RW;
    return 0;
}

static int __init mod_init(void)
{
    make_rw((unsigned long)table);
    original_read = table[__NR_read];
    table[__NR_read] = modified_read;
    return 0;
}
static void __exit mod_exit(void)
{
    table[__NR_read] = original_read;
    make_ro((unsigned long)table);
}

module_init(mod_init);
module_exit(mod_exit);
```

EDIT:

I applied the fix to the function pointer and edited the code to match the one presented in the second link. The print from within `modified_read` never comes up in `dmesg` despite running some example C code with `read()`. Also, if I remove the macros for write protected memory (and leave the `make_ro`, `make_rw`), the code crashes on insmod. I left both there, for reference. Any suggestions?

```c
#define DISABLE_W_PROTECTED_MEMORY \
    preempt_disable(); \
    barrier(); \
    write_cr0(read_cr0() & (~ 0x00010000));

#define ENABLE_W_PROTECTED_MEMORY \
    write_cr0(read_cr0() | 0x00010000); \
    barrier(); \
    preempt_enable();

asmlinkage long (*original_read)(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);
asmlinkage long modified_read(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count) {
    pr_info("sys_read\n");
    return original_read(fd, buf, count);
}

unsigned long *table = (unsigned long*)0xc16e7180;

int make_rw(unsigned long address){
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(address, &level);
    if(pte->pte &~_PAGE_RW){
        pte->pte |=_PAGE_RW;
    }
    return 0;
}

int make_ro(unsigned long address){
    unsigned int level;
    pte_t *pte = lookup_address(address, &level);
    pte->pte = pte->pte &~_PAGE_RW;
    return 0;
}

static int __init mod_init(void)
{
    DISABLE_W_PROTECTED_MEMORY
    make_rw((unsigned long)table);
    original_read = (void*)*(table + __NR_read);
    *(table + __NR_read) = (unsigned long) modified_read;
    make_ro((unsigned long)table);
    ENABLE_W_PROTECTED_MEMORY
    return 0;
}
static void __exit mod_exit(void)
{
    DISABLE_W_PROTECTED_MEMORY
    make_rw((unsigned long)table);
    *(table + __NR_read) = (unsigned long) original_read;
    make_ro((unsigned long)table);
    ENABLE_W_PROTECTED_MEMORY
}

module_init(mod_init);
module_exit(mod_exit);
```

Comment: Unrelated to your questions, `void **table = (void *)0xc16e7180;` shouldn't compile, because `void**` is not compatible with `void*`. No idea what you are actually trying to do here.

Comment: This line of code was taken from the first link. After fixing the function pointer (from user253751's answer), the print line from ```modified_read``` never shows up in ```dmesg```. Perhaps it's related to your remark. Would you have any suggestions?

Comment: I have no idea about the code is supposed to do, only that it isn't valid C and doesn't make any sense as it stands.

Answer (score 3):

`original_read` is a function. You cannot assign to a function. For example, you couldn't do `printf = something;`

It seems that you meant for `original_read` to be a function pointer. To declare a function pointer, you need an extra set of parentheses:

```
    asmlinkage long (*original_read)(unsigned int fd, char __user *buf, size_t count);
                    ^              ^
```

Comment: Thank you. The compilation finishes with no errors once I applied your fix. However, the ```pr_info``` from within ```modified_read``` still doesn't show up in ```dmesg``` despite running an example C code with ```read()```. Would you have any suggestions? I've always got stuck on this issue.

Comment: I used ```grep sys_call_table /boot/System.map``` to get ```c16e7180 D sys_call_table```. I assigned the first value to the variable. There is a lot of similar examples online which seem to work for everyone, but whenever I apply them to my VM with a newer kernel, the code does nothing. I'm missing something, so I thought I'd post this question here.